# pwm msp432 led blinking

Tags: microcontroller, led, pwm

Im currently working on setting up led blinking on the board but the human's eyes cannot see it but when i record using camera i can see the blinking (after extracting the frames) . i believe our eyes can only see up to 24fps ~30 fps and the frequency is 60hz. Also, from what I understand from some research 20% duty cycle at 100 hz will look steady compared to 20%duty cycle at 10hz which will look like it on and off. I also read somehwere online that if 75% duty cycle the LED does not blink at all compared to 50% duty-cycle. can you explain more about this? do i need to change the duty cycle or the frequency to make the led only visible to camera but not to our eyes?

Comment: Your eye does not respond that much differently from the camera. You can easily see a light flash of microseconds duration, if sufficiently bright. If the camera can see it, your eye probably can, unless you go outside the visible spectrum (eg, infrared).

Comment: seriously? i thought there are some projects out there been using this idea. the camera from the phone can detect led blinking but the human cant see the led blinking (they see it as steady light)

Comment: Your question says "led only visible to (the) camera but not to our eyes". Steady-appearing light is visible.

Comment: sorry im not good at words. what i meant was the led is actually blinking but eyes cant see it blinking

Comment: Your eyes can probably see the blinking of a LED that is on 1/60 of a second and off 59/60 of a second, but they will probably not notice the blinking of a LED that is on 59/60 of a second and off 1/60 of a second. Cameras work in a different way, and I would guess that most cameras that can record the blinking of a 1/60 on, 59/60 off LED, will also be able to record the blinking of a 59/60 on, 1/60 off LED.

Comment: so upshot, do i need to set the pwm frequency to be less than 1/60hz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you appear to be concerned with flicker- If there is relative motion between the light source and your eye, the image may appear to "break up". The sensors in your retina act as if they integrate over a period of time in the milliseconds, but you can see a much more brief flash- it just appears dimmer for shorter durations below the flicker fusion frequency. For example, if you whack yourself over the head with a book you may be able to see a 1kHz flash break up, but the camera frame rate will at best do some aliasing thing with the shutter speed unless it is a high speed camera. This is not a coincidence, the camera frame rate is made just fast enough to appear steady, which is much slower than what can be picked up with persistence of vision. Flicker is also more perceptible in peripheral vision, 100Hz is annoying for many people- probably an evolutionary adaptation to help our ancestors pick up rapid motion of predators or prey out of the corners of our eyes.

If there's no motion the light may appear steady above some frequency in the tens of Hz, but it will vary a bit with duty cycle, I think, probably getting somewhat worse as the duty cycle gets shorter (due to the logarithmic response). Above the flicker fusion frequency perceived brightness is lower for lower duty cycle, so a 10% duty cycle source needs to be 10x brighter to be perceived the same as a light source at 100% duty cycle.

Comment: wow too much to digest. but thank you!

Comment: Hopefully not.. The nice thing about this is that you don't need any fancy equipment to experiment beyond the camera and at least one functioning human eye. A micro, a bench frequency generator or even a nasty old 555 will work.

Comment: also, i read some stuffs online about the following. since i will be using an Iphone to record it (30fps), i can set the led frequency to 15hz, so it is visible to the camera but not our eyes. is that true?

Comment: i will be using vlc to extract frames from the video. I plan to extract every 30 frames per second. so i can see it on and off. that is my goal actually.

Comment: What is your intent? If it is to secretly pass information, the bar is much higher.

Comment: the idea is that i want to put the led on an electrical appliance. when a camera (phone) detects the led blinking, it will open a menu to control the appliance.

Comment: It all depends how smart the image recognition is at detecting and aliasing effect with the capture sweep and PWM duration and rate on what works effectively.  Some Xmas LED strings flicker at 120Hz with an AC bridge can be tested with a camera for beat pattern.

Comment: If I use my iPod camera in slo-mo mode on an LED/LCD TV, I get the strongest 4Hz alias flicker, because this is the fastest capture rate.

Comment: Save your head from that book! Look at the LED from across the room with binoculars ... the unsteadiness will move it around and you'll see discrete dots instead of a line, revealing the blinking at higher rates than normal vision.